# Get image by name in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

i want to make a custom background image, witch will be changed every day, with url to original source.
for example :

```
img name 346.jpg 
$dayofyear = date('z');
$dayofyear = Get image by name in wp?
background-image: url(<? php echo $dayofyear; ?>)
```

thx, and sorry for my English :D

Comment: yeah, and 
<a href = "<? php echo $ImageDescr (witch contain an url); ?>">Source url</a>

Answer (score 3):

Each image you upload to the media library uses the filename before the extension as it's slug.
You can use the get_posts function and pass in $dayofyear:

```
  function get_attachment_url_by_slug( $slug ) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'name' => sanitize_title($slug),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
  );
  $_background = get_posts( $args );
  $background = $_background ? array_pop($_background) : null;
  return $background ? wp_get_attachment_url($background->ID) : '';
}
```

That will return the ID of the image you're trying to get by it's slug.

If you're doing this inside a page or post template, you would use:

```
$dayofyear = date('z');
$background_url = get_attachment_url_by_slug($dayofyear);
```

Then set the inline style of the element, for example:

```
<div style="background-image: url(<? php echo $background_url; ?>);"></div>
```

This won't work if you're trying to inject this into a stylesheet.